# Default namespace not recognized and all class members 'do not exist' when working code is fetched from remote repo to a new machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an asp.net/c# web page project that was developed on one machine that builds, runs, everything without problems, but won't run on any other machine when pulling the code from a remote git repo. I realize git is probably not the issue, but mention it to provide context: this code is not mis-typed or mis-written or even mis-copied (.gitignore is blank), since it builds successfully on one machine (that is no longer available) but won't build on any other.

The Error List is several hundred lines long, basically every member used in the .aspx.cs file and defined in the .aspx file is 'does not exist in the current context'. There are also a handful of declarations that are not found in any namespace (I only use one, the default, across the project) and are "...not found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

What extra setup might the original machine have had that needs to be transferred to the new machine(s) I'll be building this code on?

[image]

```
          Login:
          </div>
          <div class="form-field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogin"  runat="server" Columns="16" ></asp:TextBox> 
          </div>
           <div class="form-label"> 
            Password:
           </div>
           <div class="form-field"> 
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Columns="16" TextMode="Password" 
                   ></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div> 
           <div class="form-label">Store Type:</div>
           <div class="form-field"> <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStoreType" runat="server">
```

```
if (dataConn.HasRows == true || txtLogin.Text != "")
            {
                ddlStoreType.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: If this is a multi-project solution, make sure all the projects loaded correctly and the correct start up project is designated. If the project linked an assembly not built by the project, be sure that assembly is loaded. If you rely on NuGet packages, be sure the packages have been restored.

Comment: Checking your project's _References_ or _Dependencies_ in Solution Explorer for missing items is a good place to start looking.

Comment: A simple guess is whether the .net environment is not installed on the target machine. I have encountered similar problems.